# Memsql is taking lot of time for a query to execute

Tags: singlestore

I am having one problem with my memsql cluster when I run the query to fetch the 51M records it returns result in 5 minutes
but it used to take more than 15 min when data insertion is  parallel to read.

I measured disk io and it is ok and the disk is hdd disk.

There are no other connections to the memsql and cpu is also 15% utilized with 64 core machine

Below are my varaiables

```
Variable_name                                | Value                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aggregator_failure_detection                 | ON                                                                           |
| auto_replicate                               | OFF                                                                          |
| autocommit                                   | ON                                                                           |
| basedir                                      | /data/master-3306                                                            |
| character_set_client                         | utf8                                                                         |
| character_set_connection                     | utf8                                                                         |
| character_set_filesystem                     | binary                                                                       |
| character_set_results                        | utf8                                                                         |
| character_set_server                         | utf8                                                                         |
| character_sets_dir                           | /data/master-3306/share/charsets/                                            |
| collation_connection                         | utf8_general_ci                                                              |
| collation_database                           | utf8_general_ci                                                              |
| collation_server                             | utf8_general_ci                                                              |
| columnar_segment_rows                        | 102400                                                                       |
| columnstore_window_size                      | 2147483648                                                                   |
| compile_only                                 | OFF                                                                          |
| connect_timeout                              | 10                                                                           |
| core_file                                    | ON                                                                           |
| core_file_mode                               | PARTIAL                                                                      |
| critical_diagnostics                         | ON                                                                           |
| datadir                                      | /data/master-3306/data                                                       |
| default_partitions_per_leaf                  | 16                                                                           |
| enable_experimental_metrics                  | OFF                                                                          |
| error_count                                  | 0                                                                            |
| explain_expression_limit                     | 500                                                                          |
| external_user                                |                                                                              |
| flush_before_replicate                       | OFF                                                                          |
| general_log                                  | OFF                                                                          |
| geo_sphere_radius                            | 6367444.657120                                                               |
| hostname                                     | ****                                                  |
| identity                                     | 0                                                                            |
| kerberos_server_keytab                       |                                                                              |
| lc_messages                                  | en_US                                                                        |
| lc_messages_dir                              | /data/master-3306/share                                                      |
| leaf_failure_detection                       | ON                                                                           |
| load_data_max_buffer_size                    | 1073741823                                                                   |
| load_data_read_size                          | 8192                                                                         |
| load_data_write_size                         | 8192                                                                         |
| lock_wait_timeout                            | 60                                                                           |
| master_aggregator                            | self                                                                         |
| max_allowed_packet                           | 104857600                                                                    |
| max_connection_threads                       | 192                                                                          |
| max_connections                              | 100000                                                                       |
| max_pooled_connections                       | 4096                                                                         |
| max_prefetch_threads                         | 1                                                                            |
| max_prepared_stmt_count                      | 16382                                                                        |
| max_user_connections                         | 0                                                                            |
| maximum_memory                               | 506602                                                                       |
| maximum_table_memory                         | 455941                                                                       |
| memsql_id                                    | **                                     |
| memsql_version                               | 5.7.2                                                                        |
| memsql_version_date                          | Thu Jan 26 12:34:22 2017 -0800                                               |
| memsql_version_hash                          | 03e5e3581e96d65caa30756f191323437a3840f0                                     |
| minimal_disk_space                           | 100                                                                          |
| multi_insert_tuple_count                     | 20000                                                                        |
| net_buffer_length                            | 102400                                                                       |
| net_read_timeout                             | 3600                                                                         |
| net_write_timeout                            | 3600                                                                         |
| pid_file                                     | /data/master-3306/data/memsqld.pid                                           |
| pipelines_batches_metadata_to_keep           | 1000                                                                         |
| pipelines_extractor_debug_logging            | OFF                                                                          |
| pipelines_kafka_version                      | 0.8.2.2                                                                      |
| pipelines_max_errors_per_partition           | 1000                                                                         |
| pipelines_max_offsets_per_batch_partition    | 1000000                                                                      |
| pipelines_max_retries_per_batch_partition    | 4                                                                            |
| pipelines_stderr_bufsize                     | 65535                                                                        |
| pipelines_stop_on_error                      | ON                                                                           |
| plan_expiration_minutes                      | 720                                                                          |
| port                                         | 3306                                                                         |
| protocol_version                             | 10                                                                           |
| proxy_user                                   |                                                                              |
| query_parallelism                            | 0                                                                            |
| redundancy_level                             | 1                                                                            |
| reported_hostname                            |                                                                              |
| secure_file_priv                             |                                                                              |
| show_query_parameters                        | ON                                                                           |
| skip_name_resolve                            | AUTO                                                                         |
| snapshot_trigger_size                        | 268435456                                                                    |
| snapshots_to_keep                            | 2                                                                            |
| socket                                       | /data/master-3306/data/memsql.sock                                           |
| sql_quote_show_create                        | ON                                                                           |
| ssl_ca                                       |                                                                              |
| ssl_capath                                   |                                                                              |
| ssl_cert                                     |                                                                              |
| ssl_cipher                                   |                                                                              |
| ssl_key                                      |                                                                              |
| sync_slave_timeout                           | 20000                                                                        |
| system_time_zone                             | UTC                                                                          |
| thread_cache_size                            | 0                                                                            |
| thread_handling                              | one-thread-per-connection                                                    |
| thread_stack                                 | 1048576                                                                      |
| time_zone                                    | SYSTEM                                                                       |
| timestamp                                    | 1504799067.127069                                                            |
| tls_version                                  | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2                                                        |
| tmpdir                                       | .                                                                            |
| transaction_buffer                           | 67108864                                                                     |
| tx_isolation                                 | READ-COMMITTED                                                               |
| use_join_bucket_bit_vector                   | ON                                                                           |
| use_vectorized_join                          | ON                                                                           |
| version                                      | 5.5.8                                                                        |
| version_comment                              | MemSQL source distribution (compatible; MySQL Enterprise & MySQL Commercial) |
| version_compile_machine                      | x86_64                                                                       |
| version_compile_os                           | Linux                                                                        |
| warn_level                                   | WARNINGS                                                                     |
| warning_count                                | 0                                                                            |
| workload_management                          | ON                                                                           |
| workload_management_expected_aggregators     | 1                                                                            |
| workload_management_max_connections_per_leaf | 1024                                                                         |
| workload_management_max_queue_depth          | 100                                                                          |
| workload_management_max_threads_per_leaf     | 8192                                                                         |
| workload_management_queue_time_warning_ratio | 0.500000                                                                     |
| workload_management_queue_timeout            | 3600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- Workload profiling (https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v5.8/workload-profiling-overview/) can help you understand what resources are limiting the speed of this query - if it's not cpu and not disk io, maybe it's network io or something
- Query profiling (https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v5.8/profile/) will help indicate which operators within the query are expensive
- You mentioned your machine has 64 cores - is your cluster properly numa-optimized? Run `memsql-ops memsql-optimize` to check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Network IO couldn't be there as my master and both of the leaf are on same machine.

I did the query profiling and as I said query used to execute and give me 51M records in less than one minute but the query only take more time when read is in parallel.

Comment: That may be expected if the queries are all using up CPU. Check what CPU usage is when the queries are running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Jack, I did the workload profiling and find out that lock_time_ms is quite high when NETWORK_LOGICAL_SEND_B is high

## LAST_FINISHED_TIMESTAMP, LOCK_TIME_MS, LOCK_ROW_TIME_MS, ACTIVITY_NAME, NETWORK_LOGICAL_RECV_B, NETWORK_LOGICAL_SEND_B, activity_name, database_name, partition_id, left(q.query_text, 50)

'2017-09-11 10:41:31', '39988', '0', 'InsertSelect_AggregatedHourly_temp_7aug_KING__et_al_c44dc7ab56d56280', '0', '538154753', 'InsertSelect_AggregatedHourly_temp_7aug_KING__et_al_c44dc7ab56d56280', 'datawarehouse', '7', 'SELECT \n    `combined`.`day` AS day,\n    `lineitem'